# Resources to get started developing a dedicated mobile site

Tags: jquery, mobile, css

I'm going to be developing a basic site for mobile and I'm wondering if there are certain limitations/requirements/resources I should know when starting a mobile site project.

Basically, it's going to be a simplified version of the desktop site and when the user goes to www.example.com, it will be redirected to mobile.example.com.

Some things I would like to know:
- how to accomodate for the number of different mobile phones and their different viewport dimensions
- using javascript vs. css3

Any good resources that could help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery mobile http://jquerymobile.com/ is a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

Look into Sencha Touch. http://www.sencha.com/products/touch

also phonegap http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile